# How do I ensure inserted date stays inserted until checked box is unchecked?

Tags: javascript

Per this code below, when users check a box, date is automatically inserted into a textbox control called cDate. This works great:

```
function ClickBox(cb) { 
    var tr = cb; 
    while (tr.tagName != "TR") { 
        tr = tr.parentNode; 
        if (tr == null) return; // something went wrong 
    } 
    var inps = tr.getElementsByTagName("input"); 
    for (var i = 0; i < inps.length; ++i) { 
        var inp = inps[i]; 
        if (inp.name.indexOf("cDate") >= 0) { 
            inp.value = rightDate(); 
            break; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

These are the affected controls:

```
    <ItemTemplate> 
     <asp:CheckBox ID="myrecord" runat="server" onclick="ClickBox(this)" /> 
    </ItemTemplate>  

   <ItemTemplate> 
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" style="border: none;" ID="cDate"></asp:TextBox> 
   </ItemTemplate>
```

The issue users are currently having is that once a checkbox is checked and date is inserted, only way to remove the inserted dates is the click the Reset button.

They would prefer to have the inserted dates disappear once a checked box is unchecked.

This modified code below isn't working.  I am not getting any errors, however, whenever I am checking a box or unchecking it, nothing is happening - no date is getting inserted anymore.

```
function ClickBox(cb) { 
        var tr = cb;
        var inps = tr.getElementsByTagName("input"); 
        if(cb.checked == 1){ // CheckBox checked condition 

                while (tr.tagName != "TR") { 
                        tr = tr.parentNode; 
                        if (tr == null) return; // something went wrong 
                } 
                for (var i = 0; i < inps.length; ++i) { 
                        var inp = inps[i]; 
                        if (inp.name.indexOf("cDate") >= 0) { 
                                inp.value = rightDate(); 
                                break; 
                        } 
                } 
        } 
        else{ 
                for (var i = 0; i < inps.length; ++i) { 
                        var inp = inps[i]; 
                        inp.value = ''; 
                } 
        } 
}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple solution that works for me:

ASP.NET Markup:

```
<div>
  <asp:CheckBox ID="cbDate" runat="server" onclick="ClickBox(this)" />
  <br />
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function ClickBox(checkbox) {
  var dateCheckbox = checkbox;
  var dateTextBox = document.getElementById("txtDate");

  if (dateCheckbox.checked === true) {
    dateTextBox.value = "TODAY";
  } else {
    dateTextBox.value = "";
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sameer for your response but each time I click a checkbox, I get "object expected" error on this line: <asp:CheckBox ID="cbDate" runat="server" onclick="ClickBox(this)" />.

Not sure how this works for you.

Comment: Hmmm it could be many things, @Kenny - what browser/s are you using (include versions)? My solution works on `Chrome 21`, `Firefox 15`, and `Internet Explorer 9`. You should check the JavaScript settings on all of your browsers. Also, check the HTML generated from your ASP.NET markup and ensure that `<asp:CheckBox ID="cbDate" runat="server" onclick="ClickBox(this)" />` outputs to `<input id="cbDate" type="checkbox" name="cbDate" onclick="ClickBox(this);" />`